# Inequality involving $\left(1+\frac 1n \right)^n$

Tags: inequality

Given $n\in\Bbb{N}$, prove that

> $$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n<\left(1+\frac 1{n+1}\right)^{n+1} ...(1)$$

I notice that this is approaching $e$ as $n$ approaching $+\infty$. Further more, I am asked to prove another similar inequality as following,

> $$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{n+1}>\left(1+\frac 1{n+1}\right)^{n+2} ...(2)$$

I tried to use induction method to prove them but it seems like I got stuck. Solution and hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n}}&=\frac{\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}}\\ &=\frac{n+2}{n+1}\left(1-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)^n\\
&\ge\frac{n+2}{n+1}\left(1-\frac n{(n+1)^2}\right)&\text{(Bernoulli ineq.)}\\&=
1+\frac1{(n+1)^3}\\&>1\end{align}$$

Comment: Or perhaps more directly $\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{\frac{n+1}n} \geqslant 1 + \frac1n$ By Bernoulli’s inequality...

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

If $f(x) = (1+1/n)^n$ and $g(x) = \ln f(x)$, it suffices to prove that $g(x)$ is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the binomial theorem:

$1 + n\frac 1n + \frac {n(n-1)}{2}\frac {1}{n^2} + \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{2}\frac {1}{n^3} + \cdots $

Which we can rewrite as

$(1 + \frac 1n)^n = 1 + 1 + (1 - \frac {2}{n})  + (1 - \frac {2}{n})(1 - \frac {3}{n}) + \cdots $

Note that there are $n+1$ terms

Now consider:

$(1 + \frac 1{n+1})^{n+1} = 1 + 1 + (1 - \frac {2}{n+1})  + (1 - \frac {2}{n+1})(1 - \frac {3}{n+1}) + \cdots $

Every term in $(1 + \frac 1{n+1})^{n+1}$ is greater than the corresponding term in $(1 + \frac 1{n})^{n}.$  And, it has one additional term!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the general case of
$$f(a,b)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+a}\right)^{n+b}$$ Take logarithms and expand as Taylor series for large values of $n$
$$\log\big( f(a,b) \big)=1+\frac{2 (b-a)-1}{2n}+\frac{6 a (a-b+1)-3 b+2}{6n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Continue with Taylor series using
$$f(a,b)=e^{\log\big( f(a,b) \big)}$$ $$f(a,b)=e\left(1+\frac{2 (b-a)-1}{2n}+\frac{36 a^2-48 a b+36 a+12 b^2-24 b+11}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$

Apply to the two cases, that is to say show that $f(0,0)<f(1,1)$ and $f(0,1)>f(1,2)$.